# In a pandas DataFrame with readings for multiple systems, how can I calculate daily averages and select the most recent average for each system

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, calculation

I have imported my data set to a pandas DataFrame. Each row is one reading (amplitude) from a specific system (id) at a specific time stamp (time_stamp). There are multiple readings from each system.

I would like to select the most recent daily average for each system.

This is an example of my data set:

```
df.head(6)

                 time_stamp     amplitude
id      
id1     2018-06-19 00:36:00     16163.1
id1     2018-06-19 01:19:00     16399.7
id1     2018-06-19 01:24:00     16463.3
id1     2018-06-19 03:51:00     16139.4
id2     2018-03-17 03:41:00     11886.0
id2     2018-03-17 03:41:00     12293.6
```

The column with the time stamps has been converted to pd.TimeStamp:

```
df.dtypes

time_stamp        datetime64[ns]
amplitude         float64
dtype: object
```

I have started off by calculating the daily average for each system.

To do so, I have replaced the time stamps with dates, grouped the rows by system id (the index) and calculated the mean for each date. This creates a DataFrame with MultiIndex ['id', 'date']

```
av = df.copy()

# work with dates rather than time stamps
av['date'] = av.time_stamp.dt.date
av.drop('time_stamp', axis=1, inplace=True)

# calculate daily means for each system
av = av.groupby([av.index,'date']).mean()
av
                    amplitude
id      date    
id1     2018-03-17  13923.500
        2018-04-17  14130.325
        2018-12-22  13532.650
id2     2018-03-17  12234.720
        2018-04-17  12367.050
id3     2018-06-19  16291.375
```

At this point I get stuck.

Can someone please suggest how I might create a new DataFrame with the most recent averages for each system. Something like this:

```
            date     amplitude
id      
id1     2018-12-22  13532.650
id2     2018-04-17  12367.050
id3     2018-06-19  16291.375
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html), inversing mask by `~` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df)
             time_stamp  amplitude
id                                
id1 2018-06-19 00:36:00    16163.1
id1 2018-06-18 01:19:00    16399.7
id1 2018-06-18 01:24:00    16463.3
id1 2018-06-20 03:51:00    16139.4
id2 2018-03-17 03:41:00    11886.0
id2 2018-03-17 03:41:00    12293.6

#simplfying solution
av = df.groupby([df.index, df['time_stamp'].dt.date.rename('date')]).mean()
#alternative
#av = df.groupby([df.index, df['time_stamp'].dt.floor('d').rename('date')]).mean()
av = av[~av.index.get_level_values('id').duplicated(keep='last')]
print (av)
                amplitude
id  date           
id1 2018-06-20    16139.4
id2 2018-03-17    12089.8
```

If convert `MultiIndex` to columns use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
av = df.groupby([df.index, df['time_stamp'].dt.date.rename('date')]).mean().reset_index()

av = av.drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
print (av)
    id        date  amplitude
2  id1  2018-06-20    16139.4
3  id2  2018-03-17    12089.8
```

Comment: Your solution works - thanks - I just need to ensure that the 2nd level of the index (the dates) are sorted